# jquery mobile - how to keep element selection in list?

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile

I'd like to keep element selection in list, unfortunately selection is cleared, when clicking on other element or even without any click.

See for example in http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/listview/index.html sections Formatted content and Theme.

I'm using chrome 32.0.1700.68 beta-m on windows for test.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Could you perhaps override the jquery-mobile CSS with your own using `!important`?

Comment: create a custom and use `.toggleClass("class")` in clicked item.

Comment: i've introduced a new class, that looks like ui-btn-active, that i add it on click event to clicked element and remove it from other elements.